# posgresql: how to declare variables with DECLARE command?

Tags: postgresql

I've searched and found a similar question posted over a year ago, but the proposed answers (2) don't address my question.

The page at https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/declare_vars.php described how to delare a variable with the declare command, but when I tried an example, such as

```
DECLARE vSite varchar := 'TechOnTheNet.com';
```

I got the error below.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "varchar"
LINE 1: DECLARE vSite varchar := 'TechOnTheNet.com';
```

When I looked up the syntax of the declare command, I got the following info, which is for something completely different from what's described in the above page.

```
=# \h declare
Command:     DECLARE
Description: define a cursor
Syntax:
DECLARE name [ BINARY ] [ ASENSITIVE | INSENSITIVE ] [ [ NO ] SCROLL ]
    CURSOR [ { WITH | WITHOUT } HOLD ] FOR query

URL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-declare.html
```

Comment: You can only declare and use variables when using PL/pgSQL, not in plain SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. i'm not familiar with PL/pgSQL, but when I tried to add PL/pgSQL with the sql command "create extension plpgsql", I got the error message "ERROR:  extension "plpgsql" already exists". I just ran the commandline client psql, do I need to run a different command or run psql with some options?

Comment: You need a stored procedure, function or do block that is written in PL/pgSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name okay I think I know what's going on.  the declare statements have to be in a procedure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, thanks.  what's interesting though is that I got the error while I tried to test codes from a github repo which are supposed to be run in a procedure, but didn't explicitly specified so. Guess for people familiar with PL/pgSQL would immediately knew about it when seeing declare statements.

Comment: FYI, the techonthenet link you posted is useless. I would stay away from that site in the future. What was the GitHub repo and the code you tried?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks. here is the link to the repo https://bertwagner.com/posts/converting-json-to-sql-server-create-table-statements/ i still have problems to get the codes to run, e.g. got error from the first statement (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON").

Comment: That is because the code is for SQL Server not Postgres. You need to pay attention to what you are reading.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver okay. thanks.  do you think it's relatively simple to convert it for postgres? I haven't closely examined the codes yet.

Comment: @Shiping PostgreSQL has excellent JSON support. If you are wanting to store JSON in PostgreSQL and query it, instead of parsing it and then storing in a database table, you can store the JSON in a jsonb datatype and then query it. https://dzone.com/articles/using-jsonb-in-postgresql-how-to-effectively-store. Feel free to update your question with what you are desiring.

Comment: @zedfoxus thanks for the info.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you post your comments as an answer so I can mark my post as answered? I don't want to delete the post because the comments may also be useful for others who are in similar situation.